# When is "may" a fact?

Tags: figurative-language, modality

Why is "may" found in sentences that express fact? For example:

> "They **may** be friends, but that doesn't meant that they don't fight."
>
> "I **may** be 63, but I can still dance out the evening."

Answer (score 3):

In the context of your two examples "may" means "despite" or "even though". It is not expressing uncertainty about the subsequent fact.

> "**Even though they are** friends, it doesn't meant that they don't fight."
>
> "**Despite being** friends, it doesn't meant that they don't fight."
>
> "**Despite being** 63, I can still dance out the evening
>
> "**Even though I am** 63, I can still dance out the evening

or you could rewrite the sentences with the same meanings.

> They fight despite being friends.
>
> I can still dance out the evening even though I am 63.

Answer (score 0):

> We may go to the super-bowl.

That is when may is not used to express a fact.

> I may be an American, but I am rather a loyalist (tory) and would have supported the UK during the American Revolution. (This is true).

That is when may is used to express a fact. Just read it to yourself to find out if it makes sense at all.

And if you want to know why: there are many ways of expressing something. May means maybe. Maybe I am 63, but I can still dance out the evening. It is only up to us to determine whether something makes sense or not. If that’s the way our ancestors said it, (who knows what was going on in their brain at that time), that’s the way it is, the first way, or the most recently edited way.

I hoped this helped you understand why *may* is used to express a fact.

Answer (score 0):

This sentence structure:

> _____ may be _____, but _____.

is a common [figure of speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figure_of_speech). It literally expresses uncertainty, but that's deliberate understatement.

To understand its effect, imagine that it's a reply in a conversation like this:

> Grandson: But grandpa, you're 63 years old! Don't you need to get some sleep?
>
> Grandpa: I **may be** 63 years old, but I can still dance all night!

Grandpa's point is that the grandson is wrong. Pretending that his age is unknown is a snappy way to say that his age *doesn't matter*—contrary to what the grandson thinks. If we spelled it out in more detail, it could go like this:

> Grandpa: Maybe I'm 63 years old and maybe I'm not. Either way, I can dance all night.

---

By the way, in speech, "may be" in this figurative sense usually comes out with the words "may" and "be" both fully stressed. To be especially sarcastic, you would even lengthen the word "be" or raise the pitch of your voice a bit on that word. Usually when saying "may be" ordinarily, as in "It's after 8:00 p.m., so the pharmacy may be closed," the words "may" and "be" are said quickly and with little stress or emphasis. In that sentence, the syllables "pharm-" and "closed" get full stress, and none of the syllables in between.